# Deployment order of execution

Tags: unit-test, deployment, metadata-api, metadata, destructivechanges.xml

Can You please tell me when I am using command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest "<source>" --testlevel "RunAllTestsInOrg" --ignorewarnings --apiversion "55.0" --predestructivechanges "<folder_dir>" --postdestructivechanges "<folder_dir>"
```

What is the order of execution?

Is it:

1. predestructivechanges
2. deployment package
3. postdestructivechanges
4. unit tests

Or is it:

1. predestructivechanges
2. deployment package
3. unit tests
4. postdestructivechanges

Thank You!

Comment: Without actually knowing the answer, it would seem very odd if the tests were run prior to stuff getting removed from the target org, otherwise you could end up with tests which pass before changes happen which would make them fail. Frankly, I'd be amazed if your first suggestion isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests don't run until the component changes are validated. If you've ever watched a large deployment in Setup > Monitor Deployments, you'll always see the first circle where the metadata is validated, then you'll see a second for the unit tests. If any other way was possible, it would be easy to design a situation where you could put your org in to an unusable state. I couldn't find any documentation for this, so I guess you'd just have to experiment if you wanted to confirm this for yourself.